# What's wrong with this jQuery Ajax/PHP setup?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a search app which uses Ajax to retrieve results, but I'm having a bit of trouble in how exactly to implement this.

I have the following code in Javascript:

```
if (typeof tmpVariable == "object"){
    // tmpVariable is based on the query, it's an associative array
    // ie: tmpVariable["apple"] = "something" or tmpVariable["orange"] = "something else"
    var sendVariables = {};
    sendVariables = JSON.stringify(tmpVariable);
    fetchData(sendVariables);
}

function fetchData(arg) {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "script.php",
        data: arg,
    });
}
```

And within **script.php**:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']));
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: is that the real code? may be `parse_str()` will work. `$data = parse_str(stripslashes($_GET['data']), $dataArray);` and then `foreach($dataArray['tmpVariable'] as $d){ echo $d;}`.

Comment: @StevenWorks - Nope, didn't change anything. But I think I've isolated the cause to being the javascript portion, because currently all javascript on my page is broken, but if I comment out the function, everything works normally.

Comment: What's the JavaScript Error?

Comment: @Sam - I just figured it out, the }) at the end of %.ajaxSetup was reversed... how trivial! But the PHP isn't working as expected.

Comment: What's the PHP output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script is expecting a GET var called 'data'. With your code you're not sending that.

Try this:

```
if (typeof tmpVariable == "object"){

    var data = {data : JSON.stringify(tmpVariable)}; // Added 'data' as object key

    fetchData(data);
}

function fetchData(arg) {

    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "script.php",
        data: arg,
        success: function(response){

            alert(response);

            $("body").html(response); // Write the response into the HTML body tag
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, that looks like it should work, but nothing is being echoed on the webpage. How should I make the echoes appear? Sorry if it's something basic, but I'm still trying to grasp the workings of Ajax.

Comment: Yeah that's not how it works. You're sending data to the PHP script 'in the background', which will 'respond' by echoing $d (several times). But you won't see that in the browser unless you do something with that response. I'll edit my answer to show you an example. In the meantime, do you have Firebug (Firefox) or web inspector (Chrome etc) so you can see the GET request and response?

Comment: This works marvelously. You have definitely helped me understand Ajax better. Thanks!